# How to convert from Varbinary(MAX) into Video or Audio format in c# WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

i am using Visual studio 2010, and used LINq to SQL to upload both videos or audios to the database in datatype Varbinary(max).   I now need to retrieve these files and display on xaml screen.  Can anyone help?   Here is  how i retrieve it from database and so far i added it to a byte [] array..  (assuming this is what you do??)

var fileValue = from s in context.Stimulis
              where s.stimID == 1
              select s.stimFile;

byte[] file = fileValue.Single().ToArray();

I've read that using File.WriteAllBytes() or something like this but i dont know if this is what i need to do.
Thanks Emma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not considered a good practice to store big images or videos inside a database. It is much better to organize them in a structured folder in the disk, and store in the database the paths to the files.

If you really need to store them in the database, your question depends on the files format and the API's you use. If you need to read them from disk, your approach is correct:

```
File.WriteAllBytes (strng path, byte[] bytes)
```

then you can access the file to load it with the API's you're using.

Still I recommend to store the big files outside the database.

EDIT: I think I went too far saying it's not a good practice to store them on database :). But I still think is useful to have them outside the database.

SECOND EDIT: From your comment of converting any media to one file type... this is not possible. You can convert between different audio types, or between different image types, but not any media type into a single file type. I thought your question was more focused on storing and retrieving blobs to/from database, hence my answer.

Images can be viewed in XAML, but audios and videos are another thing...
I would start by taking a look into embedding Windows Media Player into your application:
[Windows Media Player SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758070%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
so you can reproduce anything that WMP can play :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, when u say its better save them on disk and just save the path to file in database, do u mean, disk as in client machine? or save them somewere in the program?             The file formats would probably a few different video/audio types, which i could save as binary in the database and was hoping that i could convert them all back to just 1 type of file (if that was possible?). for exampl have them all mpeg when wanting to view them on screen.

Comment: @Emma Mack - You can store the files in the same disk where the DB lives, or in another drive in the same machine. Organize them in folders as you want (e.g. per type, with subfolders per day or month, ... what suits the best your application). Then just store in the database the information you want to show the user (e.g. name, creation date, origin, whatever... AND the path to the file). Systems that manipulate images, videos, etc... use to work this way.

Comment: @Emma Mack - I've edited my answer adding more info. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Haplo, i need to do a bit more homework on playin video/audio in wpf first then.  and will still want to store them to be used later, so i think i will definately try saving them on disk and save the path name in database. Thanks for you help